# Display author name, outside the loop, if they haven't published a custom post

Tags: author, user-meta, publish

I'm having trouble trying to display the current logged in author's first_name even if they haven't published a custom post outside the loop. Could someone get me started please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

author's name or logged in user's name?

can use `global $current_user;` or `wp_get_current_user();` if the user is logged in.

```
if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    echo $current_user->user_firstname;
}
```

for specific user role you can check `$current_user->roles` array.

Reference: 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo

Comment: Better answer than mine.

Comment: Logged in author's name

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
$user = get_current_user_id();
$userdata = get_userdata($user);
$firstName = $userdata->first_name;

echo $firstName;
```

Keep in mind this will only work if a user is logged in, so it's probably good to put a conditional around it to check, like so:

```
$user=get_current_user_id();
if($user) {
    $userdata = get_userdata($user);
    $firstName = $userdata->first_name;

    echo $firstName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to retrieve details of current user:

```
<?php  
    if(is_user_logged_in() ){
    $current_user = get_currentuserinfo();
    echo 'User first name: ' . $current_user->user_firstname . '<br />';
   }
?>
```